Override parameter in Bicep template through Azure ADO
I am trying to pass a variable dynamically from the Yaml file to my bicep file, but no luck.
Please note overrideParameters: '-capital_env $(environment) based on this.
I also tried
param capital_env=''
and
param capital_env
and
param capital_env string
in my bicepparam file but no luck.
I also tried overrideParameters: '-capital_env DEV' in my yaml file, but this one also did not work.
I have this yaml file:
parameters:
- name: environment
  displayName: 'Environment'
  type: string
  default: 'DEV'
  values:
  - DEV
  - TST
  - PRD

trigger: none
pr: none

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: 'Deploy to $(environment)'
  jobs:
  - job: DeployDev
    displayName: 'Deploy to Development Environment'
    condition: eq('${{ parameters.environment }}', 'DEV')
    pool:
      name: 'PartnerPortal'
    variables:
      azureServiceConnection: 'AzON-TST'
      resourceGroupName: 'rgname'
      location: 'australiaeast'
      templateFile: '.\Infrastructure\DEV\mainStorageAccountCreation.bicep'
      parametersFile: '.\Infrastructure\DEV\mainStorageAccountCreation.bicepparam'
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo "Listing files in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
        dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
        echo "Listing files in $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Infrastructure\DEV\"
        dir $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\Infrastructure\DEV
      displayName: 'List files in working directory'
    - script: |
        echo "Current PATH: $env:Path"
        az --version
      displayName: 'Verify Azure CLI Installation'
    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      inputs:
        deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
        azureSubscription: '7c0513a'
        ConnectedServiceName: 'AzON-TST'
        resourceGroupName: $(resourceGroupName)
        location: $(location)
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(templateFile)'
        csmParametersFile: '$(parametersFile)'
        overrideParameters: '-capital_env $(environment)'
      displayName: 'Deploy ARM Template to DEV'

I have this bicepparamter file:
using 'mainStorageAccountCreation.bicep'
param capital_env='dfd'
param lower_env = toLower(capital_env)
param encryptionScopeName = 'defaultEncryptionScope'
param publicNetworkAccessLappFapp = 'Disabled'
param publicNetworkAccessApp = 'Enabled'
param ipWhitelist= [
  '203....' //my IP
]
param storageAccountsApp = [
  'uwasydstapartp${lower_env}'
]

param storageAccountsfapplapp = [
  'uwasydstapartptla${lower_env}'
  'uwasydstapartptli${lower_env}'
]

and this my bicep file
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param capital_env string
param lower_env string = toLower(capital_env)
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'
param encryptionScopeName string
param publicNetworkAccessApp string
param publicNetworkAccessLappFapp string
param storageAccountsApp array
param storageAccountsfapplapp array
param ipWhitelist array
module storageapp '../modules/StorageAccountApp.bicep' = [for storageName in storageAccountsApp: {
  name: storageName
  params: {
    location: location
    storagename: storageName
    encryptionScopeName: encryptionScopeName
    publicNetworkAccessApp: publicNetworkAccessApp
    ipWhitelist:ipWhitelist
  }
}]



module storageappfapplapp '../modules/StorageAccountLappFapp.bicep' = [for storageName in storageAccountsfapplapp: {
  name: storageName
  params: {
    location: location
    storagename: storageName
    encryptionScopeName: encryptionScopeName
    publicNetworkAccessLappFapp: publicNetworkAccessLappFapp
  }
}]

the module for creating the storage account
param storagename string
param location string
param encryptionScopeName string
param publicNetworkAccessApp string
param ipWhitelist array // Array of IP addresses to whitelist
resource storageAccount 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2023-01-01' = {
  name: storagename
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'Standard_LRS'
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  //Optional. Set the extended location of the resource. If not set, the storage account will be created in Azure main region. Otherwise it will be created in the specified extended location
  
  properties: {
    accessTier: 'Hot'
    allowBlobPublicAccess: false
    allowCrossTenantReplication: false
    allowedCopyScope: 'AAD'
    allowSharedKeyAccess: false
    defaultToOAuthAuthentication: false //A boolean flag which indicates whether the default authentication is OAuth or not. The default interpretation is false for this property.
    //dnsEndpointType: 'string'
    encryption: {
     
      keySource: 'Microsoft.Storage' //Microsoft-managed keys
      
      requireInfrastructureEncryption: false
      services: {
        blob: {
          enabled: true
         // keyType: 'Account'
        }
        file: {
          enabled: true
         // keyType: 'Account'
        }
        queue: {
          enabled: true
         // keyType: 'Account'
        }
        table: {
          enabled: true
         // keyType: 'Account'
        }
      }
    }
    
    isHnsEnabled: false
    isLocalUserEnabled: false
    isNfsV3Enabled: false
    isSftpEnabled: false
    
    minimumTlsVersion: 'TLS1_2'
    networkAcls: {
      bypass: 'AzureServices'
      ipRules: [
        for ip in ipWhitelist: {
          action: 'Allow'
          value: ip
        }
      ]
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
    }
    publicNetworkAccess: publicNetworkAccessApp
  
   }
}

resource encryptionScope 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/encryptionScopes@2022-09-01' = {
  name: encryptionScopeName
  parent: storageAccount
  properties: {
    source: 'Microsoft.Storage'
  }
}

I am not able to pass capital_env from the yaml to bicepparam successfully, what changes I may need to do to fix this?
I am expecting to pass the capital_env to my bicepparemter file.

you don't have a variable $(environment)? are you trying using ${{ parameters.environment }} ?

Do I need to have a variable, I assumed the parameter will work

I also hadcoded DEV but it did not work overrideParameters: '-capital_env DEV'

Do you know which bicep version it is running?

added that info, @2023-01-01

Sorry I was wondering the az bicep version  When you run the task in ADO it should output these info int he log task at the beginning

In the log task, you should also see the az cli / az powershell command that it is executing

Task         : ARM template deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template to all the deployment scopes
Version      : 3.243.0
****in the self hosted agent:

az --version
azure-cli                         2.63.0

core                              2.63.0
telemetry                          1.1.0
Dependencies:
msal                              1.30.0
azure-mgmt-resource               23.1.1

did I answer your question correctly?

Yep that's what i was looking for ^^

Hi @MohsenUWA, is the deployment successful in the pipeline? If there is any error message, please share it. As you have tried to hardcode DEV but it did not work overrideParameters: '-capital_env DEV' , maybe you can try simplifying your Bicep
template to make it easier to spot the problem.

thanks heaps, I will go through yours and try to see what mistake I made, hopefully I can spot it quickly, thanks heaps

Hello @MiaoTian-MSFT, one quick difference with mine is that you are using storagePrefix as parameter both in yaml and bicep, while it is not the same for me

One more question: If mutliple vars needs to be passed, what shall I change in the override section, I assume one part if having multiple parameter for each variable

Hi @MohsenUWA, I updated my answer with two overrideParameters. The usage of multiple parameters is like overrideParameters: '-storagePrefix  ${{ parameters.Prefix }} -storageSKU ${{ parameters.SKU }}'

thanks a lot for adding two vars, I tried it but again it creates it based on the value which is in the bicepparam and not in the yaml file, the other difference is that you using the passed param, i.e. storagePrefix, in your main.bicep file, which for me is the module, does this make sense to you? I am using the passed var in the parameter file and not in the main.bicep file

thanks for the code,  It seems I found the issue, we do not need to define override param as an individual param in the yaml file, it muse be used in the bicep and not bicepparam. We only need to define it in Yaml as param if we want to get it from user through a drop down list

@MohsenUWA, glad to hear that you have solved the issue! Happy coding!

I tested to override parameter in Bicep template with the task AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3 in my pipeline and it works.
The YAML of my pipeline:
parameters:
- name: SKU
  type: string
  default: 'Standard_LRS'
  values:
  - Standard_LRS
  - Standard_GRS
- name: Prefix
  type: string
  default: 'dev'
  values:
  - dev
  - prd
trigger: none

steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ConnectionName'
    subscriptionId: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
    resourceGroupName: 'Group'
    location: 'Southeast Asia'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/templates/template.bicep'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/templates/template.bicepparam'
    overrideParameters: '-storagePrefix  ${{ parameters.Prefix }} -storageSKU ${{ parameters.SKU }}'
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

So, the overrideParameters in your case should be '-capital_env  ${{ parameters.environment }}'.
Here are my test Bicep files to create a storage account (referenced here):
Files in the repo:

template.bicep
@minLength(3)
@maxLength(11)
param storagePrefix string

@allowed([
  'Standard_LRS'
  'Standard_GRS'
  'Standard_RAGRS'
  'Standard_ZRS'
  'Premium_LRS'
  'Premium_ZRS'
  'Standard_GZRS'
  'Standard_RAGZRS'
])
param storageSKU string 

param location string = 'southeastasia'

var uniqueStorageName = '${storagePrefix}${uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)}'

resource stg 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts@2021-04-01' = {
  name: uniqueStorageName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: storageSKU
  }
  kind: 'StorageV2'
  properties: {
    supportsHttpsTrafficOnly: true
  }
}

output storageEndpoint object = stg.properties.primaryEndpoints

template.bicepparam
using 'template.bicep'
param storagePrefix='test'
param storageSKU='Standard_LRS'


The storage account deployed with the pipeline:

